# Error: Sharepoint 2010 Web Part. Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sp2010 website where I am trying to use a network path for the images as I have a WebFarm which is loadBalanced using CISCO ACE appliance hardware (without IP Stickiness). The reason I am using a network shared folder is that at times the Chart does not show the PNG images. I am using UpdatePanel with Timer to update the chart every minute.

The problem with displaying the PNG images in the Web Farm comes when I had initially the web.config setting as shown below.

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=10;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
```

So I used the network Shared path as per the article, where I have FULL Permissions on EVERYONE, NETWORK Service.

Below is my current setting for the Network shared folder path and I keep getting this error: Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=10;dir=\\servername\TempImageFiles\;" />
```

Can someone help.

Rgds,

SSP

Comment: How do you call the ChartImageHandler?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot give a UNC path in chart's `dir` attribute, instead what you can do is to map the network path to a drive on your servers and use that path as chart's `dir` value e.g 
map `\\servername\TempImageFiles\` to `z:\` drive and use this

```
       value="storage=file;timeout=10;dir=z:\;"
```